# The Mothers' Riddle

Tags: riddle

Not to be confused someone better known

Our children are hundreds in number

We never shield them

They must fend for themselves

We like our homes

If you disturb us you'll find our bite is worse than our bark

Be aware when time is red

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is a

> Black Widow

Not to be confused someone better known

> Not sure yet, possibly the marvel character

Our children are hundreds in number

> Egg sacs are full of hundreds of spiders

We never shield them

> Marvel character is part of SHIELD, but that's not the black widow that this puzzle is referring to

They must fend for themselves

> Children eat each other while young, they must fight to survive

We like our homes

> Web-spinning spider, stay close to it

If you disturb us you'll find our bite is worse than our bark

> Don't make a sound but have a deadly venom

Be aware when time is red

> The red hourglass on their abdomen is their most defining feature

Comment: Correct, the only thing you have wrong the the third line.

Comment: Does it have something to do with S.H.I.E.L.D.?

Comment: yes, it's a reference to the first line

Answer (score 1):

An alnswer has already been selected but you could be a

> Seal

Kind of a reach but here it goes -

Not to be confused someone better known

> Navy SEALs are better known

Our children are hundreds in number

> Seals usually breed in [colonies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinniped#Reproductive_behavior) where there are hundreds of children

We never shield them

They must fend for themselves

> Their children are out on their own. It's a battle for survival *(technically no, but let's run with it :) For my answer that second line is redundant anyway)*

We like our homes

> Most species of seals favor polar icy climate even though they stay in water  *(I mean who doesn't like their home. It's called home for a reason)*

If you disturb us you'll find our bite is worse than our bark

> The sound that seals make is called [bark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tx9JH.png). As for the bite, walruses are a species of seals, and have you seen their teeth.

Be aware when time is red

> When the time is red, could mean if someone is injured and there's blood around, they have to be careful of sea predators like sharks, that can smell blood.

Comment: Interesting take on it. I like it.